# Relations between variance and SD when adding up the variables

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, standard-deviation

If $\sigma(X+Y)=10$ (the numbers are not independent), would $\mathrm{var}(X+Y)$ simply be $10^2=100$? Don't see it in my textbooks and haven't exactly found an answer online.

Answer (score 4):

Standard deviation is a square root of variance and variance is a square of standard deviation. It does not have different definitions depending on what random variable it is relates to.